# Adapt to screen res

Tags: html, css, background, resolution, scaling

So for some reason my webpage displays just fine on my main screen but it screws up on my second monitor. Main screen res: 1440x900, second screen res: 1280x800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issues is that you are telling it how many pixels to go over to the right for your middle section. The way you are coding it will never appear correct unless everyone that uses your website is using the same screen resolution as your main monitor.

What you should do instead is use [relative positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), or probably easiest and most browser friendly is to use a framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) that helps you to lay things out the way you want.

also - removing horizontal scroll is as easy as saying `overflow-x: hidden` as a css property on the body or something else that is causing your side scroll

Comment: if i set positioning to relative it dissapears completely?

Comment: Yea... as mentioned [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) it is the most confusing option of all the positioning attributes. I only put it in the answer since it is an option available to you to use. Personally I would go with the bootstrap grid system that they have, or use the flexbox idea.

Comment: With all due respect i understand even less of that. I'm relatively new to all this coding stuff thanks for the effort put into anwsering my question. I will however ask my teacher for some explanation as far as the bootstrap idea.